How to replace icon in instance of a component in Figma?
Requirement:
I used same icons for the navigation items at the beginning of the time but after creating the Figma design I want to change and use specific icons for the specific item.
Problem:
I am not able to change icons for the instances of the component.
and all the icons are placed on the frame.
